# How can I find out how much current/power my phone can supply via USB-OTG?

Tags: usb-on-the-go

Is there a way to find out how much current or power a USB-OTG device can draw while connected to my phone? I'd be happy with something like:-

- an online database like GSMArena with details for lots of phones
- an app I can run on the phone to find it out e.g. from the USB host driver in the kernel
- a file in `/proc` or `/dev` I can read (as root, if necessary)

I'd rather not have to test it with hardware by connecting a USB peripheral to it and increasing its current draw until it stops working.

The particular phone I'm interested in is a Nexus 5, but I'm really looking for an answer that's applicable to any phone (that supports USB-on-the-go).

Comment: You can try the [Battery Historian](https://github.com/google/battery-historian) tool(written in Python & Go programming) to analyze your battery consumption details with a graphical view. I don't have an USB OTG device to test this tool. So I'm not sure if this will surely help you. But you can give it a try. Hope this helps ;)

Comment: Did you ever find a way to know this?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure this is entirely correct on Android, but on Linux, `lsusb -v` tells a lot about USB devices, including their maximum current output. If you can get usbutils on Android, that might tell you.

Comment: Wouldn't that only tell me the max current draw requested by a connected peripheral?

Comment: Hmm, oh well. @Dan Hulme You could get around that by plugging in something that you know will request a lot, like another phone or a battery pack.